# Edit Text without ID or specified class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I am currently starting **javascript** working on a website that is provided by a host where i only can change specified parts of the website. In fact, i should be able to change all content via javasript because i am able to include javascript in the header. I already did this so far with success, but i m stuck at a point where i cant find a further answer, so here are the facts:

The unchangeable **HTML** Code looks like this:

```
<div>
  <intput .... />
  <intput .... />
  <intput .... />
  <intput .... />
  <div> ... some unimportant informations ... </div>
  <hr />
  <strong> SOME TEXT: </strong> additional text with important things to change
  <hr />
</div>
```

**Issue :**

How to select the text which i want to change.

**What i tried but with no success:**

```
$("*").each(function() {
  $("this:contains('important things to change')").replace('important things to change', 'new text here');
}
```

What is the correct way to achieve the needed.

Comment: Your actual question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to target the text of the parent div that follows the strong tag without impacting the contents of the child elements?

Comment: Maybe talk to your host about changing other things? Users without JavaScript enabled will still see the old content. Users on slow connections (or busy times of day) will see the old content for a moment then it will be replaced. Search engines will not be able to crawl the content, and might even punish you for such bizarre behaviour…

Comment: @isherwood, yes - that is exactly what i mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of ways you could do it, if you know where that div is, you can find it by:

If its next to the first `'<hr/>'` inside the body:

```
$('body hr:nth-child(1)').next().html("anything you wana write");
```

Its the second div inside the `"#somediv"`:

```
$('#somediv div:nth-child(2)').html("Anything you wana write");
```

or its the 5th child inside `body`:

```
$('body:nth-child(5)').html("anything");
```

or its a parent of `"#thisdiv"`:

```
$('#thisdiv').parent().append("write anything");
```